# How to detect window of site being closed in express.js?

Tags: express, socket.io

For socket, we use-

```
io.on('disconnect', () => {
  ...
  });
```

The commands executes a code when the window is closed or refreshed. I tried using it for my purpose, but I couldn't manage to make it work. Because I need cookies from the browser to update a mongodb collection, which in the way I tried- didn't work.

Can anyone tell me how can I do it? Even if it's with socket?

I want to do something like the following-

```
io.on('disconnect', () => {
  const account = require('./server/models/account');
  const idCode = req.cookies.idcode;
     await account.updateOne({Code:idcode},{response:'yes'})
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your issue correctly, I have a similar scenario and I solved it basically by keeping a `map<string, IWebSocket>` in memory, where the string is a generated UUID. As I have no database in the background, I have no need to use another map for storing real Id's.

Basically the code looks like this:

```
public initializeService(expressWs: expressWs.Instance): void {
    const router = Router();
    const wss = expressWs.getWss();
    wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => {
      // handleConnect will create a participant which contains the websocket and store this information
      this.handlerService.handleConnect(ws);
      
      ws.on('close', (_number: number, _reason: Buffer) => {
        // handleClose will use the websocket to find the participant and to the necessary
        this.handlerService.handleClose(ws);
      });
    });
    // I only have one route processing every type of message coming in
    router.ws(
      '/:team',
      (ws, req, _next) => {
        ws.on('message', (msg: string) => {
          try {
            const message: AClientMessage = JSON.parse(msg);  
            // again the handlerService uses the websocket to find out who is the sender          
            this.handlerService.handleMessage(message, req.params.team, ws);
          } catch (error) {
            this.handlerService.handleError(ws, error as Error);
          }
        });
      });
  }
```

As sockets only exist as long as the server is running, it is save to store the socket information in memory. You could store anything in the map and replace the UUID by a database user id after a login message.
I took this approach as I wanted a cookie-free website.